# Cannot programatically select top row in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I've spent yesterday and today on this trivial/basic task, seems like I've tried everything:

```
ui->left_panel->selectRow(0);
ui->left_panel->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex
 (file_system_model_.index(0,0), QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

`file_system_model_` is `QFileSystemModel`
and
 `left_panel` is `QTableView`.
Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `ui->left_panel->selectionModel()->select(file_system_model_.index(0,0), QItemSelectionModel::Select | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);` ?

Comment: @vahancho just now ;) Doesn't work ;(

Comment: Are rows selectable at all? Which selection behavior set for the table view? Try with different `QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags`.

Comment: @vahancho yes, the rows are selectable, Just to clarify, by select I mean highlight it. And if I click on a row with my mouse everything works, but I cannot do it from code.

Comment: Selection behavior is set to ui->left_panel->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);

Comment: Well, I would check also whether `file_system_model_.index(0,0)` returns a valid model index. Also will try with, as I said, various QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags

Comment: @vahancho  file_system_model_.index(0,0) does return a valid ModelIndex. I need selection flags to be set to SelectRows.

Comment: Have you tried other rows/colums? Do they work? This may not be a solution, but if you can select the second column in the first row, the whole row gets selected

Comment: @Felix yes, I've tried that, it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ui->tableVIew->setCurrentIndex(ui->tableView->model()->index(0,0));
```

Assuming that your selectionBehavior is by SelectRows, this will be enough.